# Is it possibble to reboot a remote MySQL server on Ubuntu from a program or script on a Mac?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mac

I have a client who has a web server hosted with Digital Ocean and they have a weird random MySQL database issue...

1-4 times a month there database server crashes and has to be manually rebooted.

I have not been able to figure out the cause of this random crash so I currently have to do this process each time it happens:

1. Open a terminal command prompt window
2. type and run: `ssh root@IP-HERE -l root`
3. type in the server user password: `server-user-password`  v
4. type and run the command: `service mysql restart`

This reboots the MySQL server and all is great again until a week or 3 later when it randomly happens again and then repeat process.

---

As my client has no server admin experience and doesn't even know what a command prompt/terminal window is or looks like...I need to come up with some solution that would allow anyone, including a monkey to be able to replicate the process outlined above when I am not available!

Some info:

- **Developer/Admin (me)**: running a Windows 7 PC
- **Client**: is running a Mac OS X (newest OS w/e it is)
- **Server**: is running Ubuntu 12.0.4

With that info, would it be possibble to build some sort of 1 click solution script where the client could click and launch a script/program from his Mac which would auto-run the process above to reboot his MySQL server when this emergency issue comes up for him and I am not around to help?

Comment: Do you have any webserver on the server, for e.g. apache?

Comment: Get someone to solve the real problem.

Comment: The db seems to need repair. Maybe even the OS is broken, which happens from time to time, if eg HDD errors occured. Dump the DB, setup a fresh virtual machine, redump the database and watch.

Comment: Also try reinstalling the sqlserver with the --reinstall option. **Backup** /etc and /var/lib/mysql dirs before and you can even purge and reinstall.

Answer (score 4):

You ever thought about monitoring the MYSQL Server?

Maybe Nagios is too big but whats with a script and a cron or monit is also very lightweight.

Monit provides a very easy basic webfrontend where you also can restart the services.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be using [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/). It's a lightweight utility for monitoring and managing daemons or similar programs.

Install monit

```
# aptitude install monit
```

Create conf file for mysql

```
# cat /etc/monit/conf.d/mysql
check process mysqld with pidfile /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
group database
start program = "/etc/init.d/mysql start"
stop program = "/etc/init.d/mysql stop"
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 3306 then restart
if 5 restarts within 5 cycles then timeout
```

Restart monit

```
# service monit restart
```

Check mysql status

```
# netstat -an | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

# service mysql status
mysql start/running, process 33446
```

Stop mysql server (just to emulate some problems)

```
# service mysql stop
```

Check monit log file

```
[EEST Mar 30 12:34:10] info     : 'ubuntu14' Monit started
[EEST Mar 30 12:36:10] error    : 'mysqld' process is not running
[EEST Mar 30 12:36:10] info     : 'mysqld' trying to restart
[EEST Mar 30 12:36:10] info     : 'mysqld' start: /etc/init.d/mysql
[EEST Mar 30 12:38:12] info     : 'mysqld' process is running with pid 34085
```

In a few minutes it restart mysql server

But it's just a workaround, as @lain has mentioned you should find the root of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have (to generate if not existend and) to transfer you ssh keys to the server (to achieve passwordless login):

```
ssh-copy-id root@IP-HERE
```

Login to the server and set up a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
service mysql restart
exit 0
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

On your client, you want to call the script via ssh. Simplify the execution of the following ssh command (Use [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus) or Apple Automator, etc. as wrapper):

```
ssh root@IP-HERE -l root script.sh
```

Now you can pass a clickable server-restarter to your clients.

BTW: You should resolve the issue, not build a crappy reboot-workaround.
I assure you, there will be more headache utilizing this reboot workaround than fixing the problem. Like peabody said, you should look at munin or monit to detect the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about manual restarting, it is too slow and need you or client (you want to go to holiday sometimes, aren't you?). Just setup some monitoring and do it automatically. `Zabbix` and `Nagios` are good for overall monitoring, but maybe too big for one server. You can setup `monit` to check your mysql and do restarts for you automatically and near instantly.

But you're fixing symptom, not cause, which is bad. You have to found real reason why is mysql crashing (enable more verbose logging, monitor another metrics of server) and fix it.